# Force view text file instead of download in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, preview

Often times I'll click on a random link to a `.sh` or `.py` or `.cpp` or ... file in Firefox, and all I want is to view the code. I don't have a Firefox handler set up for every text file extension under the sun, and I don't want to have to. Is there an easy way to force Firefox to view the file as text instead of trying to save (or open in external app)?

Comment: Possible same on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191925/how-to-force-firefox-to-open-a-file-which-does-not-have-a-txt-extension-as-if-i

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe you should give [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8207) a try.  I've never used it but it looks like it might work for you.

Comment: I use that addon, it works pretty well.

Comment: Good old firefox...this was originally reported as a bug 9 years ago. This extension was made 3 years ago. Bug still not fixed...but at least I can use the extension.

Comment: Yes this is a great addon. It's really annoying that the world is moving away for this way of working (take chrome that wants to save everything)

Comment: Yes, the [Open in Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-browser/) add-on is the best solution until something as simple is integrated into Firefox (but I fear it never will...).

Answer (score 0):

Open options and go to the applications tab, maybe that will help. Other than that, I'm not sure. Try searching for an extension.

Comment: Applications tab: that would require me to add something for each and every file type, I was hoping to do it all at once. extension: I looked, but couldn't find any that did what I wanted. Hence why I am asking on here

Answer (score 0):

Answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860875/why-txt-file-in-iframe-is-getting-downloaded-instead-of-displayed/47340441#47340441)

to display file add below line(s) in .htaccess

```
AddType text/plain .txt
AddType text/plain .log
```

This is signal Firefox that you don't have to download the file instead view file as plain text.This technique can be applied to all the files that you need to view instead off download.

Comment: This is server-side configuration. If it is configured properly, things work. But more often than not it is configured wrong, and the point is working around that bad configuration.