# How to have Firefox save txt files automatically instead of opening in browser

Tags: firefox

When I click on a txt file I would like the browser to save it to the default download folder instead of opening it in the browser directly.

I have checked `Options --> Applications` to determine how the browser handles `text/plain` content types and beside "text document" it says "Save".

In the `mimetypes.xml` file under the current firefox profile, this entry refers to `text/plain` documents, so it should save the files automatically.

However it is still being opened directly in the browser. Is there a different setting that I need to change? I know with PDF files, firefox 18 or something came with a special pdfjs extension that overrides my own settings and had to be disabled in the configuration, but not sure if there is something sneaky like this for plaintxt files.

I tested it on links to txt files from http://www.textfiles.com/history/

I am using the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: Closely related: http://superuser.com/questions/586719/download-text-plain-instead-of-opening-in-browser I also came here because of textfiles.com !

Answer (score 2):

Simply **right-click** the link and **Save Link as**.

OR

Go to **about:config** page in Firefox, then set **browser.altClickSave** to **true** then you can force a download if you hold down the **Alt key** and **left-click** the link.

Comment: I want the browser to automatically download txt files, just like how it automatically downloads PDF files or MP3 files.